# Где допущена ошибка в использовании гема Gretel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Созданы**:
**контроллер**: posts.rb

**модель**: post.rb

**Вьюшка**: index.html.erb & show.html.erb

добавляю в Gemfile

```
rails generate gretel:install
```

устанавливаю гем:

```
bundle install
```

Инициализирую гем в самом проекте:

```
rails generate gretel:install
```

После выполнения этой команды создаётся конфигурационный файл примерно:

```
config/breadcrumps.rb
```

Туда записываю строки

```
crumb :root do
  link "home", root_path
end

crumb :posts do
  link "post", posts_path
  parent :root
end
```

В файл views/posts/layouts/application.rb записываю:

в views/posts/show.html.erb записываю:

```
<% breadcrumb :posts %>
```

**Результат**:

```
Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #291 raised:

undefined method `breadcrumbs' for #<#<Class:0x007fd8934484f0>:0x007fd893527a60>

Extracted source (around line #291):

289
290
291
292
293
294




        <!--<li class="active">Here</li>-->

        <%= breadcrumbs pretext: "Сейчас тут: ", separator: " &rsaquo; " %>
      </ol>
    </section>


:
```

Comment: Сервер перезагружали?